# Running e-commerce site from a web service. Bad idea?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

The company I work for makes a complex accounting application. This is a desktop app that connects to a local database server on the client's network. Some of our clients want to get e-commerce sites built but they will need access to this data.

Is it OK to install the web site at one location and feed data to it from a web server in another location. I've built stuff like this in the past and I know it could potential be slow. I'm hoping to mitigate this problem with stacks of Asp.NET caching. Is this a reasonable architecture (for a small to medium size e-commerce site) or will it run like a dog? Due to much pain in the past, I'm trying to keep this simple and avoid any sort of replication of the database.

Cheers
Ma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, replication of the database might actually be the fastest option. Think about it: getting a whole bunch of data on each request, with some cache misses, or basically having a 'complete' local cache (and thus no cache misses, well, not in-transfer anyway, your DB might cache, of course).

Edit: so basically my answer would be: no, it's not OK to run the website and database in two completely different locations. Two boxes in the same rack could be OK, but it seems that it would be preferable to have your web-service and DB on the same (virtual) machine.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Zsub. Yes I'm sure a local db would be faster but it's a lot of extra complexity. I haven't used Asp.NET caching a lot but I figured that I could cache by querystring (eg ProductList.aspx?productCategoryId=123). Now I'm realising that some customers have special prices so that will make it difficult to cache. With those type of customers there will have to be a call to the service at each page load. It will slow things down but I'm still thinking of trying it.